# SQL JOIN with WHERE condition when two rows' values are the same and one row matches to two different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union, where-clause

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE students(
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE studentsActivities(
  studentId int NOT NULL,
  activity VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (studentId, activity),
  foreign KEY (studentId) REFERENCES students(id) 
);
```

And I have to return all student names that do either Tennis or Football. However, there was a test case which I could not pass and it was stated like that:

> Students with the same name.

I do not know the exact implementation of the test cases, but I suspect it was the situation where student A named Carl does Tennis and student B also named Carl does Football and Carl is showed two times. How could I query that database to get the result like that? I've created the demo base to try:

```
CREATE TABLE students(
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE studentsActivities(
  studentId int NOT NULL,
  activity VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (studentId, activity),
  foreign KEY (studentId) REFERENCES students(id) 
);

INSERT INTO students 
VALUES
(1, "Jeremy"),
(2, "Hannah"),
(3, "Luke"),
(4, "Frank"),
(5, "Sue"),
(6, "Sue"),
(7, "Peter");

INSERT INTO studentsActivities
VALUES
(1, "Tennis"),
(1, "Football"),
(2, "Running"),
(3, "Tennis"),
(4, "Football"),
(5, "Football"),
(6, "Tennis");
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6fc3c)
And let's suppose that the passing set would be:

```
Jeremy 
Luke 
Frank 
Sue 
Sue
```

I've attempted with these two queries, but none gives the correct answer.

```
--- 1
SELECT s.name
FROM students s
JOIN studentsActivities sa
ON sa.studentId = s.id
WHERE activity = "Tennis"
UNION
SELECT s.name
FROM students s
JOIN studentsActivities sa
ON sa.studentId = s.id
WHERE activity = "Football"
--- Returns Frank Jeremy Luke Sue (missing one Sue)

--- 2
SELECT s.name
FROM students s
JOIN studentsActivities sa
ON sa.studentId = s.id
WHERE activity = "Tennis"
OR activity = "Football"
ORDER BY s.name;
--- Returns Frank Jeremy Jeremy Luke Sue Sue (too much Jeremies)
```

Comment: "student names that do either Tennis or Football" is at best ambiguous. Names don't do sports, students do sports, so it doesn't even make sense. Please quote the exact specification. There is a difference between names of students that do either T or F & names for which a student they name is in T or F. Moreover the result you give isn't even a set, it's a bag, so you need a specification that describes the bag(s) allowed, and if order is involved, you need a specification that describes the list(s) allowed. (Likely it would be a bag/list got from an SQL bag "projection" of a row set/list.)

Comment: And what do you think is a correct characterization of what each of your queries returns, in terms of the meanings/predicates of the base tables? (We can expect that the given specification is the assignment writer's wrong characterization of their own query returning that list.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the tables, filter only the rows with the activities that you want and return distinct rows:

```
select distinct s.id, s.name
from students s inner join studentsActivities a
on a.studentId = s.id
where a.activity in ('Tennis', 'Football')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hKvBivLu5zSp4xGpg37xJi/0).

Results:

```
| id  | name   |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | Jeremy |
| 3   | Luke   |
| 4   | Frank  |
| 5   | Sue    |
| 6   | Sue    |
```

If you want only the names of the students without the ids:

```
select s.name
from students s inner join studentsActivities a
on a.studentId = s.id
where a.activity in ('Tennis', 'Football')
group by s.id, s.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hKvBivLu5zSp4xGpg37xJi/1).

Results:

```
| name   |
| ------ |
| Jeremy |
| Luke   |
| Frank  |
| Sue    |
| Sue    |
```

Comment: See my comment on the the other answer, which applies here too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists`:

```
select s.*
from students s
where exists (
    select 1 
    from studentsActivities sa 
    where sa.studentId = s.id and sa.activity in ('Tennis', 'Football')
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0768bdebe88d93a15fea91d82bbc07eb)**:

```
id | name  
-: | :-----
 1 | Jeremy
 3 | Luke  
 4 | Frank 
 5 | Sue   
 6 | Sue
```

Comment: But it cannot reasonably be said that that result--which is given in the question--satisfies the specification given in the question. See my comment on the question. Of course, we can expect that the given specification is the assignment writer's wrong characterization of their own query returning that list.